# Iterate and publish array values using helper in Meteor

Tags: meteor

I'm getting results from the Yelp Search API into a client-side collection in a Meteor.js app. I am successful in inserting the results into the client-side collection (results are only stored temporarily). From the browser console:

```
Object {region: Object, total: 3720, businesses: Array[10]}
```

The `businesses` array contains the 10 results I would like to pass into a template helper and display in a table:

```
businesses: Array[10]
0: Object
1: Object
2: Object
3: Object
4: Object
5: Object
6: Object
7: Object
8: Object
9: Object
```

Each object in the array contains fields, and even more arrays, such as "name" and "stars", which I need to access in the table.

I've been successful in getting a helper to reach the document (with `region`, `total`, and `businesses`) but I can't get the values beneath it. This is as far as I've gotten:

```
Template.YelpAdd.helpers({    
results: function () {
            return YelpSearchResults.find().businesses;
        }
});
```

In the template:

```
<table>
          <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Type</th>
              <th>Neighborhood</th>
              <th>Address</th>
          </tr>
          {{#each results}}
                  <tr>
                      <td>{{name}}</td>
                       <td>...</td>
                       <td>...</td>
                       <td>...</td>
                  </tr>
          {{/each}}
</table>
```

I know this is possible, I'm just getting stuck. Perhaps there is another way to get this done by manipulating the results before I insert them into the `YelpSearchResults` client-side collection.

Comment: Is there more than one document in `YelpSearchResults`? If no, then I think you want `YelpSearchResults.findOne().businesses;`. If yes, then do you want to combine all `businesses` into a single array?

Comment: There may end up being more than one document in the collection in the future, but for now, one document at a time suffices. Thank you @DavidWeldon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[find](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/find) returns a cursor. It sounds like you want [findOne](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/findone) which returns a document (which you can use to access the list of `businesses`). Give this a try:

```js
Template.YelpAdd.helpers({    
  results: function() {
    var yelpResult = YelpSearchResults.findOne();
    return yelpResult && yelpResult.businesses;
  }
});
```

Note that I added a [guard](http://dweldon.silvrback.com/guards) in case the yelp result isn't actually available when the helper first runs.